# What is meant by the term "DBset can be used when the type of entity is not known at build time"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is meant by the term

> DBset can be used when the type of entity is not known at build time

in this sentence :

> DBSet class represents an entity set that is use for create, read, update, and delete operations. A generic version of DBSet (DbSet) can be used when the type of entity is not known at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine you want to create a repository for easier data access, but you don't want to create a separate repository for each DBSet (or table in your database) you have. Instead you can create a generic repository and once you initialize this repository-object, you can add the information which DBSet you want to address with this repository-object.

The repository would look something like this

```
public class Repository<T> where T : EntityObject
{
    public Repository(YourDBContext context) {
        _context = context;
        if(_context != null)
        {
            _dbSet = _context.Set<T>();
        }
    }

    /* add methods for insert, update, delete, etc... */

    private YourDBContext _context;
    private DBSet<T> _dbSet;
}
```

So for example you have the DbSets User and Comment. Instead of creating the repositories UserRepository and CommentRepository you can now use the generic repository for both DbSets:

```
using(YourDBContext context = new YourDBContext())
{
    Repository<User> userRepo = new Repository<User>(contex);
    userRepo.Insert(userEntity);
    Repository<Comment> commentRepo = new Repository<Comment>(context);
    commentRepo.Delete(commentEntity);
}
```

Of course if there is more to the repository pattern but this is only meant as an example. And to sum up your question what the sentence means: When you want to generalize which DbSet you want to address with a class, you can make the class generic and add the information (about which DbSet to address) later at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact context of that message but you can do that by using DbSet to use a generic type.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks..But i want to know what is meaning of build time in this sentence :DBset can be used the type of entity is not known at build time

Comment: It means that it can allow you to specify dynamic types to use as entities. I have never tried it and I think you also need to create a custom dbcontext that derives from DbContext and in OnModelCreating.
I have found more info [here](http://romiller.com/2012/03/26/dynamically-building-a-model-with-code-first/).